# Hiding empty inputs by parent row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr class="row">
        <td class="field">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   ...
   ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to hide the `<tr>` with the `class="row"` but only when the input within the `<td>` with the `class="field"` is empty when the page loads.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

`$('td.field:text[value=""]').parents('tr.row').hide();`

However, for some reason, this DOES work:

`$('td.field).parents('tr.row').hide();`

(ie: it hides all of the rows with `class="row"`)

Also, the following DOES work:

`$('td.field:text[value=""]').val('test');`

(ie: all empty inputs are populated with 'test' on page load)

I'm new to JQuery so I'm suspecting that I may have just misunderstood the way chaining works. can anyone give me any pointers? It semms like the two parts of what I am trying to do are correct when attempted separately, but don't work together as one.

Comment: hide tr when all `field` are empty or if just one is empty?

Comment: In this case, I wanted to hide the tr if the row was incomplete in any way, so the answer below works well. If I wanted to only hide if ALL of the fields were empty, then I guess I'd hide all of the tr first and then use $('td.field').children('input:text:not([value=""])').parents('tr.row').show(); to show the ones I wanted, unless there's a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be in this way:

```
$('td.field :text[value=""]').parents('tr.row').hide();
```

**The reason:** :text (input) is child from td.field. If you put td.field:text it's wrong because they are diferente selectors.

Comment: Aargh, just one little space! :-) I just tried it and it works, thanks! I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes when the limit has been removed! Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: In other words, `td.field:text` selects elements of class `field` with `type="text"`, and (note the space) `td.field :text` selects children of elements with class `field` with `type=text`.

Comment: Thanks James, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

and why dont you go the oposite way - select the INPUT with empty value, and than go to its

parents().parents().hide()

first parents to get TD, the second one to get TR

Comment: Ordinarily, that'd work, yes. However, the inputs are automatically generated by another system and I am not able to control the class or id of them, so I can't select them directly.